# how to pass parameter name as a databasename in pentaho BA Server?

Tags: database-connection, reporting, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have scenario where i have one table in one database which consist all the database names,so in drop-down container i am displaying all this database name, now in another query i want to pass this database name as a parameter and want to retrieve data from the respected table.

Note : database structure is same for every client, but security reasons we have created different databases

Query one : using this i will get all the database names.

```
SELECT tenant from kscommon.organization;
```

Query two : tenant will be parameter for next query

```
select location from ${tenant}.organization;
```

but i am getting error(Error processing component)

SO can somebody guide me on this?

Comment: What step are you using? How are you passing the tenant variable? What error are you getting?

Comment: i am using the simple procedure, in one sqljndi connection i am giving query one so i am getting all the tenant values in one drop down, now i am expecting to work as what ever the tenant value i will select from drop down it has to go as a parameter in query two, so in second sqljndi i am writing second query.

i am getting error message saying : error processing component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this scenario but unable to achieve this but according to my experience you can use parameter in query conditions only. you will not able to use parameter name while creating database connection because if you are doing so that means you are trying to create multiple database connections during query level which i believe pentaho doesn't support at present.
In CDE you can explicitly create multiple connections and then try to use it when ever it required.

Still you can wait for other to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a Kettle (aka Pentaho Data Integration) transformation

Comment: i am aware with KETTLE alternative.
so how can i take the data from kettle to CDE?
on dashboard i have drop down where i will select field which is actually DB name.
so once i will select dbname then how it will execute on reverse/pdi level?

Comment: You should add a datasource referencing your Kettle transformation and configure its parameters in the same way as with a sql query and use a parameter in order to associate your select field with your datasource.

Comment: So will it be real-time? i mean to say if i select parameter then how transformation/job will execute?
any reference or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it works like any CDA request : there will be a GET request toward your Database that will return the result.